# A short way to make Updates/Deletions to several database's tables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I have an application on vb.net that use a Sql server Database.

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1

The database has a lot's of tables (100+)

-On some tables there's a field "DelDate"  (Date)

-On some tables there's a field "DelChilds"  (Bit)

Is there a short way to do these operations :

1) Delete all records from all tables that have the DelDate= "01/01/2014"

2) Update the "DelChilds" field  on all the records ( for example set  to True )

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Dynamic Query using `sys.column` and `sys.tables` and `execute` them in a batch .
You can call `Stored Procedure` to achieve this functionality using entity framework .

Procedure Code

```
 Create Procedure UpdateDelete @date Date = '01/01/2014'
AS 
Begin 
Declare @DelQuery Nvarchar(Max),@updatequery Nvarchar(Max),
select @DelQuery = Stuff( (
select  ' Delete from ' + t.name + ' where   DelDate = ''' + Convert ( varchar,@date,110) + ''';'  from sys.columns C JOIN  sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where C.name = 'DelDate'   for XMl Path('')),1,1,'')

select @DelQuery
Exec sp_executeSQL @DelQuery

select @updatequery = Stuff( (
select  ' UPDATE ' + t.name + ' SET  DelChilds = 1 ;'  from sys.columns C JOIN  sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where C.name = 'DelChilds'   for XMl Path('')),1,1,'')

--select @updatequery
Exec sp_executeSQL @updatequery
END
```

For DelDate

```
select  'DELETE FROM ' + t.name + ' WHERE DelDate = ''01/01/2014'' ' + Char(13) + 'GO ' from sys.columns C JOIN  sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where C.name = 'DelDate'
```

For Delchilds

```
    select  'UPDATE ' + t.name + ' SET  DelChilds = 1 ' + Char(13) + 'GO ' from sys.columns C JOIN  sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where C.name = 'DelChilds'
```

Comment: how these can be executed through Entity framework , and Why you have use "Delete from..." for Delchilds because this field should be updated.

Comment: If you like this way (EF bypass) you can execute it via Context.Database.Connection. If you use SQL Server specify dates in yyyymmdd otherwise your program works only in US :)

Comment: Only some of the tables have "DelDate" fields , and only some of the tables have "DelChilds" field. Does these queries works on this case ? And how to run this using Entity Framework ?

Comment: @alex you can use procedure to do this . create a procedure and call that procedure in your code . I have updated in my answer .

Comment: @Arun ok but I get the date 01/01/2014 as an example. what if the date is a variable ?

Comment: you can pass parameter to the procedure .

Comment: @Arun  ok , maybe I'm wrong , but what will do your code on tables that doesn't have those fields ? Because not all tables have those fields

Comment: @Alex those tables will not consider which does not a have `DelChilds` and `deldate`  fields .

Comment: @Arun I have problems in the case when a record that should be deleted has children ( that should be deleted too). I get error in this case.( Of course if the parent has the Deldate= "01/01/2014" , all its children have the same value in Deldate) –

Comment: This code produce error when a parent that has childs should be deleted. What modifications should I do ?